Time Series Data with delay
I am working with two simple time-series obtained from a aquatic robot—one representing, Depth vs. Time and the Temperature vs. Time, with Time being the common factor between both series.
Basically both these sensors are mounted on the same robot, so ideally both should be changing together.
Understanding
Both Series against Time
From the graph, it’s evident that as depth increases, temperature decreases (which is obvious as the robot goes deeper in the sea the temperature should decrease).
However, there seems to be a delay in the Temperature Sensor, because as the depth gets linear (around 4 secs) after some time, the temperature continues to decrease (until around 20 seconds after which it gets somewhat linear). This suggests that the temperature sensor is detecting changes with a delay compared to the depth sensor.
My goal is to quantify this delay. Specifically, I want to determine the time taken that I can use to adjust for the delayed temperature sensor. Could someone help me on how to fit the Depth and Temperature data correctly and calculate the delay between the two signals?
I am not sure how to upload a CSV file here, so I created a google drive link where I will upload both all files for reference.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u0dLJTqJ0HSRgglT3aqwOqiglX5lpE7c?usp=sharing
I have attached Jupyter File in the google drive of what all I tried, obviously It didn't work.

You need a "static" temperature reading at the surface, and a "static" temperature reading at the target depth. When you "drop the sensor", you'll know the time it takes to reach the target depth; the sensor reading at that depth; the time for the sensor reading to match the "static" reading; with any OVERSHOOT. Then you can start smoothing. And the whole temperature thing is affected by currents on the way down.

this is more a question in physics, about the rate of cooling of the sensor given the gradient in the start. I would model for cooling of a sensor at a finite rate k, given a change the temperature it feels vs the time it take it to thermalize to that temperature. for example if it starting from T1 then linearly go to T2<T1 and stay there. while we measure something like an exponential decay (like an RC lifetime in electronics).
